# Equally divide two button width with Auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

- 2 button with equal width constraint
- My requirement is when hide button1(Order) it reflect button2(Reservation) width equal to (button1+button2) width.
- I have apply _button1widthconstrain.constant=0,but it’s not work.

Please do needful help.[image]

Comment: Have u set width constraint equal to both the buttons..!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, now you have constraints like this (1):

H:|-(0)-[order]-(0)-[reservations]-(0)-], order.width = reservations.width

You should create additional constraints like this (2):

H:|[order][constraint]|

H:|[constraint][reservations]|

, where constraint are between button and respective border of superview and has constant = 0.
Then you should set their priority to less than main constraints(1) (for example 990).

In this case, when you hide button, our additional constraints become active and make button fill all width.

Comment: How do you hide one of the buttons then ? Simply calling button.hidden=YES will not update its width, right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below github example.it will help you.
https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is that when you hide button1 (Order), button2 (Reservations) should expand and its final width should be (original) button1+button2, is that correct?

If that is the case you can do the following:

1. Add a UIView that would enclose button1 and button2. Set the constraints to that UIView so it ends up with the height you want for your buttons, with a width equals to button1+button2 (probably by setting leading and trailing constraints to its superview) and with the vertical position that you want for your buttons.
2. For button1, set the width constraint, top and bottom space to the superview to 0 (or equal height to the superview + center vertically in container), and the leading space to the container view to 0.
3. For button2, set the horizontal spacing to button1 to 0, top and bottom space to the superview to 0 (or equal height to the superview + center vertically in container), and the trailing space to the superview to 0 as well. **Do not set a width constraint for button2**

With that set of constraints, when you change the constant of the width constraint of button1 to 0, button2 should expand to the wanted size.

Answer (score -1):

Download the files in github using below link

https://github.com/damienromito/UIView-UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints

```
#import "UIView+UpdateAutoLayoutConstraints.h"
```

Take 2 NSLayoutConstraints like below

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *orderHeightCons;
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *reserHeightCons;
IBOutlet UIButton orderBtn,reservationBtn;

//Then connect at IB both Constraint & Buttons. Use Below Code For Hiding the Order Button & Modifying the Width for Reservation Button

orderBtn.hidden=YES;
//Hide Order Button..change value as per ur button height
[orderBtn setConstraintConstant:0 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight];

//if constraint doesn't exist, it will be created..change value as per ur button width
[orderBtn setConstraintConstant:0 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth];

//you can use tools to hide
[orderBtn hideByHeight:YES];

//Modify Reservation Button..change value as per ur button height
[reservationBtn setConstraintConstant:100 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight];

//if constraint doesn't exist, it will be created..change value as per ur button width..(button1+button2) height value
[reservationBtn setConstraintConstant:200 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth];

[reservationBtn hideByHeight:NO];
```

Hope it will be helpful to u..!

Comment: The minus is not mine, though the problem can be solved without dealing with constraints from code.